How to send a message to a flow in spring integration?
Suppose the following flow:
public IntegrationFlow sendFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(inputChannel())
                .handle("something","someMethod")
                .channel(outputChannel())
                .get();
}

How I do a manually put a message in the input channel?
I would like something like this:
Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test").build();
Something.submitToChannel("outputChannel", message);

Note: I am calling this from a Web Endpoint.
Thanks

Something like:
@Autowire
MessageChannel inputChannel;

...

Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test").build();
this.inputChannel.send(message);


I actually figured this out, but I used this exact solution.  Thank you.
